# Developing software for Android to Android Communication using Android ANT Radio Service

Tags: java, android, ant-radio-service

I am interested in using the ANT Radio Service in my application to be able to communicate to another Android Device. I've seen the [ANT Website and read through the documents](http://www.thisisant.com/), I also downloaded the Android API [in their software section](https://www.thisisant.com/developer/resources/downloads/#software_tab) which contains the jar, javadocs, and some sample applications written using Eclipse.

Also included were apk files of the sample applications. I installed them (Acquire Channels and Background Scan Samples), but those samples seem to just scan for available devices. The Acquire Channels Sample does not seem to work as the Background Scan Sample does not seem to find my device using the Acquire Channels App.

I am also having a difficult time importing the Eclipse Projects properly to Android Studio for some reason.

Does anyone here know how to build Android Applications with the use of the ANT Library for Android to Android communication? There seems to be a lack of examples and tutorials online for such a good technology given its age.